# PHP Form eMail + write to CSV

Tags: php, forms, csv

I have this form where I wan't people to sign up for receiving free stuff campaign. The form works fine and its send the details to the requested eMail.
Now this form should also write the details to a csv file that we can handle the data more easily.

I use this form:
     $value) {
        ${"".$key} = $value;
    }

```
if (!isset($email)) {
        header( "Location: $formurl" );
    exit;
}

if ($_POST['services']) {
  foreach($_POST['services'] as $value) {
    $check_msg .= "- $value\n";
 }
}

function is_email($email) {
    return ereg("^[^@ ]+@[^@]+\.[^@ ]+$", $email);
}

function validate_email($email) {

   // Create the syntactical validation regular expression
   $regexp = "^([_a-z0-9-]+)(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@([a-z0-9-]+)(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$";

   // Presume that the email is invalid
   $valid = 0;

   // Validate the syntax
   if (eregi($regexp, $email))
   {
      list($username,$domaintld) = split("@",$email);
      // Validate the domain
      if (getmxrr($domaintld,$mxrecords))
         $valid = 1;
   } else {
      $valid = 0;
   }

   return $valid;

}


$formurl = "/sticker/index.php" ;
$errorurl1 = "/sticker/error.php" ;
$errorurl2 = "/sticker/error.php" ;
$thankyouurl = "/sticker/success.php#start" ;

$http_referrer = getenv( "HTTP_REFERER" );


// get POST && GET vars to run with 'register_globals off'
//foreach($_GET AS $key => $value) {
//    ${"".$key} = $value;
//}

$messageproper =
"============================================================\n" .
"Sticker Request $firstname $lastname\n" .
"============================================================\n\n" .

"KUNDENDATEN\n\n" .

"Vorname: $firstname\n" .
"Nachname: $lastname\n" .
"Firma: $company\n" .
"Strasse: $street\n" .
"Strasse2: $street2\n" .
"PLZ: $zip\n" .
"City: $city\n" .
"Land: $country\n\n" .

"Telefon: $phone\n" .
"eMail: $email\n" .
"Facebook Name: $fbname\n\n" .

"--------------------------------------\n\n" .

"Bemerkung: $comment\n\n" .

"============================================================\n\n" ;

$myFile = "/sticker/sticker.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a');
$stringData = "\r\n";
$x=0;
foreach($_POST AS $key => $value) {
    $x!=0?$stringData=",".$stringData:'';
    $stringData='"'.$firstname.'";"'.$lastname.'";"'.$company.'";"'.$street.'";"'.$street2.'";"'.$zip.'";"'.$city.'";"'.$country.'";"'.$phone.'";"'.$email.'";"'.$fbname.'";"'.$comment.'"'."\r\n";
    $x++;
}
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);


$mailto = 'email@domain.com' ;
$subject = "Free Sticker Campaign: $company - $firstname $lastname";
mail($mailto, $subject, $messageproper, "From: \"$firstname $lastname\" <$email>\nReply-To: \"$lastname\" <$email>\nX-Mailer: chfeedback.php 2.01" );
header( "Location: $thankyouurl" );
exit;

?>
```

As I said nothing gets written to the CSV File I declared in $myFile.
Would be great if someone could let me know what to do.
Thanks.

Comment: Can't see anything immediately wrong, where are you expecting the csv file to be? In a folder `sticker` on your server root, right?

Comment: Yes I created the file sticker.txt in the folder "sticker" and gave it the permission 777 so it should be writable.
Now everyone who submits the form should have its details written to that csv. But when I test it, it just stays blank.

Comment: I checked everything again but still whatever I do nothing gets written to the file. Not sure whats wrong.

Comment: OK just found out that an absolute path of myFile isn't working. I deleted /sticker/ and now it works.

Comment: Good job, give yourself a pat on the back!